# What should I do when my question is marked as a duplicate and already has an answer somewhere else on Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I asked a question on [Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour), and it was marked as a duplicate of another question. I have already checked that question, and it was not useful to me. No one has answered it correctly, and even I started a bounty on that. I pointed out my doubt by commenting on highest voted answer, received reply after two days, but not so satisfying, so I posted my question again. I also mentioned in my question that I have searched on Stack Exchange, but that was not useful, and with the reason why it was not useful.

Still, my answer was marked as a duplicate. Now, what should I do?

**Edited**: Please review the question.

Comment: @Jamal not a dupe of that one.... that doesn't answer what an asker should do if they believe their question was incorrectly marked as a dupe.

Comment: Yes I agree my question is just duplicate, but I am not getting a satisfactory answer, the answer marked there, is useful to that user, not me, or you can say according to me the answer is not satisfying to the question itself. So what I should do, I already used comments, but no reply.

Comment: Put a bounty on the other question or edit yours to explain why the existing question is different.

Comment: I took a look at the question that was linked to yours, and neither of the answers was accepted by the asker (no green checkmark).  That +50 was a bounty reward, which is entirely different.